# Compass Compile Converting "\f..." to "^O..."

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass

When I run `compass compile public/`, compass converts the following styles:

```
.foundicon-rss:before {
  content: "\f002";
}

.foundicon-facebook:before {
  content: "\f003";
}

.foundicon-twitter:before {
  content: "\f004";
}
```

... to this...

```
.foundicon-rss:before {
  content: "^O002";
}

.foundicon-facebook:before {
  content: "^O003";
}

.foundicon-twitter:before {
  content: "^O004";
}
```

I'm viewing these fields via vim. It's messing up the styling of my site's icons. Is it a Foundation issue? Compass? Sass?

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/2894873c6181a8f952c0

Comment: @cimmanon Hmm, then the problem might be due to something else, I'm not sure what though. What other possible reasons could there be?